# Extracting public_profile information from facebook GraphAPI using Python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to extract publicly available information like name, location, gender, timezone and language of any person in Facebook using python.

I was able to extract the above public information for one of my Facebook friend using python package facebook, GraphAPI user Access Token and user ID using the below code:

```
import facebook
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token='Access Token from GraphAPI explorer', version='2.9')
args = {'fields' : 'id,name,location,gender,timezone,languages,locale'}
profile = graph.get_object('108155586.....', **args)
```

But when I tried the same for an arbitrary person( whose Facebook profile page contains all those information publicly) using their ID it is just outputting "name and Id" fields.

Could the extraction of Location, gender, timezone and language fields be possible in python for any person if all that information is public?

Comment: No, that is not possible. The user would need to login to your app, and grant it permissions to access this data first. Publicly available via the Facebook UI does not mean publicly available via API without restriction.

Comment: You need to get that person's `access_token' with the required permissions to view his/her data via API.

Comment: @CBroe Could I do scraping for those fields which are public on Facebook UI without violating any permissions given by facebook

Comment: Their ToS state that you are not allowed to scrape anything without their explicit, prior written permission.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my doubts!!!!